# Why is semibreve commonly pronounced as ˈsɛm iˌbriv?

Tags: pronunciation, latin, music, italian

I am seeing this on some dictionary sites:  `/ ˈsɛm iˌbriv, -ˌbrɛv /`

But, I've only heard it (in Anglophone musical contexts) as `ˈsɛm iˌbriv`.

I wasn't aware about a *cafe breve* until yesterday. This appears to be a US invention, given an Italian name, which got me to wondering about why we pronounce semibreve as we do.

Given that [the semibreve came earlier](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whole_note#History), from *semibrevis*, I'd expect that to have been preserved closer to the original pronunciation.

Is this an expected change in pronunciation coming from Latin to British English?

Comment: Trimmed first line to help focus on the briv vs brɛv without having to read the bit about cafe breve and guess context

Comment: To note that in British English, semibreve is pronounced /ˈsɛmɪbriːv/.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### This is a regular pronunciation of the letter "E" in Present-Day English

Pronouncing words spelled with the letter "e" with the sound /i/ (the sound in the word *fleece,* also transcribed /iː/, especially in British English) is an English thing. This ultimate origin of this convention is the [Great Vowel Shift](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Great_Vowel_Shift); however, aside from words that were directly affected by that sound change, there are many words spelled with "e" that entered English later, where the pronunciation with /iː/ must be due to analogy with the spelling-pronunciation patterns of other words.

One or the other of these two reasons applies to many words of Latin origin.

#### The specific history of *(semi)breve*

The pronunciation of *semibreve* in English probably comes from combining the pronunciation of *semi-* and the word *breve*, *brief.*

Here is the Oxford English Dictionary's earliest citation:

> 1594   R. Barnfield *Shepheard Content* iii. sig. Eij   No Briefes nor Semi-Briefes are in my Songs.

*Brief, breve* is taken partially from French, and partially from Latin, but it seems like the immediate source is mainly French.

The Latin word is *brĕvis,* pronounced in Classical Latin with a short vowel /ɛ/ in the first syllable. This form was not a direct influence on English.

In Old French, the following two variants seem to be found: *bref* and *brief.* I'm not sure what the full story is there, but the Oxford English Dictionary indicates that the word passed from French into Middle English in the forms *bref* and *breve,* with a number of alternative spellings, including some spellings with *ee* that indicate a "long" value for the vowel.

The spelling of *brief* with *ie* seems to have been introduced to English later.*

So I believe that *breve* is a case where the letter "e" represents a vowel that underwent the Great Vowel Shift. Both Middle English /eː/ and /ɛː/ shifted to present-day English /iː/; I'm not entirely sure which vowel this word would have had before the shift, as either could be written with the letter E.

#### It's not exactly pronounced as if it were a Latin word, but it's a bit similar

In the "[traditional English pronunciation of Latin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Traditional_English_pronunciation_of_Latin)", which is more or less a French-influenced spelling pronunciation of Latin words that originated early enough to be affected by the Great Vowel Shift, the Latin word *brevis* is pronounced /ˈbrivɪs/, while the neuter form *breve* is pronounced */ˈbrivi/.

Because the ĕ in *brĕvis* is short, a purely Latin form *semibrevis* would be stressed on the third-to-last syllable according to Classical Latin stress rules, yielding a pronunciation very different from the English pronunciation of *semibreve*. However, *semibrevis* seems to only exist in Latin post-classically. According to references I can see online, *semibrevis* occurs in the Latin text *Ars cantus mensurabilis,* by Franco of Cologne, from the 12th or 13th century, so the Latin word does appear to be attested before the OED's earliest citation for *semibreve*/*semi-brief* in English.

I doubt that the English pronunciation of Latin was a direct source of the pronunciation of *semibreve,* but it might have influenced it somewhat.

---

*"[The influence of Latin and French on the use and phonological development of the digraphs <ie>, <ea> and <ou> in English between 900 and 1800 CE](https://theses.ubn.ru.nl/bitstream/handle/123456789/6432/Kruitbosch%2C_V.C.J._%28Veerle%29_1.pdf?sequence=1)", by Veerle Kruitbosch, page 15

Comment: Breves and, therefore, semibreves were part of very early musical notation which was developed in ecclesiastical and monastic environments. I would therefore expect the names to be derived from medieval ecclesiastical Latin and the pronunciation to have similar origins.

Comment: Fascinating and helpful, thanks! The Great Vowel Shift was mentioned a few times - worth linking that somewhere?

Comment: @ljs.dev: Thanks, I added a link